# How to contact Canonical?

Tags: canonical

So I am doing a College research project for my Computer Information Systems department and it is about alternative Linux server distribution for small businesses. From my findings I would really like for this research to actually take off into a Distribution project (Using Ubuntu as a base OS).

However I would like to rename the distribution as "Bizbuntu" or something related to that ("Biz" being shorthand for business) however I don't know if I can name the distribution without consent from Canonical.

So my question is do I have to contact Canonical about this, if so, does anyone know a mailing list or email that I can contact them about this?

Comment: What's wrong with the "Contact" page on canonical.com?

Comment: My inquiry does not apply to Media, Partnering, and Customer categories, it's more of a IP inquiry...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading this: http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-rights-policy

Part 7 has "Contact us": http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-rights-policy/contact-us

Answer (score 6):

Have you visited the [Canonical web site](http://www.canonical.com/about)? You can see the contact information from there on the [about page](http://www.canonical.com/about).

Just if you couldn't find it yet, here it is:

[image: www.canonical.com/about]